# How to rotate activity, I mean: screen orientation change using Espresso?

Tags: android, robotium, ui-testing, android-espresso

I have decided that one of the testing criteria for my application tests with Google's Espresso is:

> Test should maintain Activity state after screen orientation rotation

How do I rotate the screen when using Espresso?

I have tried the following Robotium code (Yes I placed Robotium code in my Espresso test so sue me)

```
solo.setActivityOrientation(solo.LANDSCAPE);
solo.setActivityOrientation(solo.PORTRAIT);
```

but It crashes the application when I run it within my Espresso test.
Is there any way to do this?

**Thanks in advance for any help**

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515959/how-do-you-force-an-orientation-change-in-an-android-instrumentation-test

Answer (score 21):

If you have the only Activity in your test case, you can do:

### 1. Declare you test `Rule`.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TestActivity.class);
```

### 2. Get you `Activity` and apply a screen rotation.

```
mActivityTestRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
mActivityTestRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

That's a piece of pie!

Comment: This is only part of the solution. It seems that you need to wait a bit after.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it seems it works:
https://github.com/egslava/edittext-mask/blob/master/MaskedEditText/src/androidTest/java/ru/egslava/lib_phone/MainActivityTest.java#L91

Answer (score 17):

You can do it with uiautomator library

```
dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0' 
}
```

ui automator require min sdk version 18 so if your app has a lower min sdk you need to create a new `AndroidManifest.xml` in `androidTest` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package.name">
    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.test.uiautomator.v18"/>
</manifest>
```

and then in your test

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());

device.setOrientationLeft();
device.setOrientationNatural();
device.setOrientationRight();
```

Comment: This is the best way and clean one to handle orientation while testing.

Comment: this does not work if the device has auto-rotation disabled. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Kirk are you sure? If I recall correctly, it should work

Comment: @Kirk I just tested this on my phone running Android 9 and it rotates even with disabled auto-rotation

Comment: With AndroidX, the Gradle dependency is now [`androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.test.uiautomator/uiautomator)

Comment: I am a stickler to test in Jellybean (SDK 16) as a minimum, unless the whole project hinges on it, so I tried and was successful with the following without additional libraries: 
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().setRotation(UiAutomation.ROTATION_FREEZE_0);`
`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().setRotation(UiAutomation.ROTATION_FREEZE_270);`

Answer (score 8):

This [more complete solution](https://gist.github.com/nbarraille/03e8910dc1d415ed9740) creates a custom Espresso `ViewAction`and works well. It shows how to get the `Activity` (even when it is an `AppCompatActivity`) before calling its `setRequestedOrientation()` method. It also has a clean caller interface:

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(orientationLandscape()); 
onView(isRoot()).perform(orientationPortrait());
```

I follow each orientation change with a 100 ms delay, though you may not need it.

Answer (score 5):

How to rotate the screen:

```
public static void rotateScreen(Activity activity) {
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final int orientation = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()
            .getResources()
            .getConfiguration()
            .orientation;
    final int newOrientation = (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) ?
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE :
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    activity.setRequestedOrientation(newOrientation);

    getInstrumentation().waitForIdle(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }
    });

    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Screen rotation failed", e);
    }
}
```

The `Activity` can be obtained from the [ActivityRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html).

Comment: You could use `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()` instead of the `CountDownLatch`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, if you are using ActivityTestRule in order to access your activity, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule) states that this class is deprecated and you are better off using ActivityScenarioRule.

Instead of directly accessing properties of the activity, you need to put your interactions with the activity inside a runnable callback.

So the screen rotation example may look something like this:

```
    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    private fun rotate() {
        activityRule.scenario.onActivity {
            it.requestedOrientation =
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE
        }
    }
```

P.S. not sure about the proper constant to use, but `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE`(or `USER_PORTRAIT`) was the one that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix Robotium and Espresso tests. The best way sometimes to solve any issue is to check source code of desired but not comaptible method.

I'm pretty sure that you have already `setUp()` method, which has code like:

`myActivity = this.getActivity();`

Use this to change your screen orientation change:

`myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

or

`myActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

You may also need to use  `myActivity.getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();` or `Thread.sleep(milliseconds);` in order to wait for the rotation end because it is performed in Async manner. The second methods depends on emulator/device so choose it wisely.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

After my own troubles with testing of the orientation I want to add that while lelloman's advice to use `UiDevice` is correct from the documentation standpoint - unfortunately it doesn't work as expected in some cases.

I found that at least on the API 23 emulator rotation could stuck after the test's crash:

1. Do `uiDevice.setOrientationLeft()`
2. Application crashes;
3. Rotation is stuck;
   3.1 Forcing rotation through `UiDevice` works but when test ends rotation is back the wrong one until you manually change rotation to "Auto-rotate";
   3.2 `uiDevice.unfreezeRotation()` helps while test is running but after the test's end rotation is back to the wrong one.

I don't have this issue on API 28.

So I found that using `setRequestedOrientation` is the only solution for me.