# How to change the app screen orientation using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my application, I want to change the screen orientation and perform a click action on the button using Espresso.

I have tried all the solution mentioned over the internet, but nothing works. It's not changing the screen orientation. Can someone help me?

This is what I have tried:

```
ComposePageObject.clickComposeButton();
mActivityRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Do I need to create any custom class for this?

Comment: You should give more details and code templates, like which things you have tried

Comment: @HardikChauhan  - This is what I tried.                                                                         ComposePageObject.clickComposeButton();
        mActivityRule.getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Thread.sleep(5000);    Do I need to create any custom class for this?

Comment: check this solutions,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362200/how-to-rotate-activity-i-mean-screen-orientation-change-using-espresso

Comment: @HardikChauhan -  I tried some of the solutions from this blog too, but didn't work.

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question. This is better than trying to add code as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.3'
```

and with this library, write some code in your test

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
device.setOrientationLeft();
```

Check lib more, there is some other options for changing orientation