# Rotate Android Emulator In Espresso Test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I can currently rotate the display for my application from my espresso test by doing:

```
val currentActivity = getCurrentActivity()
currentActivity?.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync()
```

However, this will only rotate the display; the emulator itself remains in portrait mode.  I have the auto-rotate setting turned to on / rotate contents of the screen.

Does anyone know how to get the emulator to also rotate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rotate activity, I mean: screen orientation change using Espresso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37362200/how-to-rotate-activity-i-mean-screen-orientation-change-using-espresso)

Comment: No because I am using the suggested request orientation however it only rotates the screen, not the emulator.  I also tried UiDevice set orientation and it also only rotates the display, not the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

[You can rotate the display using emulator commands over telnet.](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)

[From the docs:](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)

```
$ telnet localhost 5554
...
auth 123456789ABCdefZ
...
rotate
...
```

(on macOS, you might need to `brew install telnet`)

Comment: I am asking how to rotate it via UI espresso test.