# How to check the orientation of my app in espresso?

Tags: android, kotlin, orientation, android-espresso, gui-testing

I am using espresso for android ui testing. I want to test whether my screen is in portrait mode. I am using Kotlin programming language.

What did I try: I tried to search how to perform this. But all I could get was change the orientation of the app using espresso.

So I tried this:

```
@Test
    fun isOrientationVertical() {
        assertEquals(resources.configuration.orientation, Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE.toString())
    }
```

However, 'resources' (to be precise, getResources()) is not getting detected.

What am I expecting: Something like this:

1. x = get the orientation
2. assert equals(if x is equal to portrait)

Thanks a lot in advance. Please do let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: what is `resources` here? a test class generally does not have any parent class, so there won't be a `getResources` method. you will need to run code in the context of your app, for example if you are using `ActivityScenario` you can run it inside a `scenario.onActivity` block (similarly for `FragmentScenario`)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591933/20356055 
Instead of `setRequestedOrientation()` you can use `getRequestedOrientation`